# POST request through php doesn't work

Tags: php, post, get

I've got a piece of code like this in my script

```
$postData = http_build_query($data);
$options = array('http' => array(
                    'method' => 'POST',
                    'header' => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' . PHP_EOL,
                    'content' => $postData
                ));

$url = 'http://evergreens.bitrix24.ru/crm/configs/import/lead.php';
$context = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
```

But the remote server 'evergreens...' responds with an error. If I make a post request with jquery it's ok but it doesn't work with php as I need to hide auth data in the script from users.
I suppose sending data has to be at exactly $_POST array, may be I'm wrong...
Originallly the error is in russian:

```
{'error':'400','error_message':'Ошибка запроса'}
```

In english it sounds like `'Request error'`.

Comment: Not all webservers accept file_get_contents with a remote URL. You can use cURL instead if this is the case.

Comment: You don't show the error message because it doesn't provide any valuable information?

Comment: What is the return for: `<?php echo ini_get('allow_url_fopen'); ?>`

Comment: I figured it out Like this 
query = http_build_query($data);
 
 $options = array('http' => array(
      'method' => 'GET',
      'header' => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' . PHP_EOL
     ));

 $url = 'http://evergreens.bitrix24.ru/crm/configs/import/lead.php?' . $query;

Comment: Is it possible that you edit the question and post the error message? Even if it's meaningless for you, some of us might extract info from it.

Answer (score 0):

Seems likeyou are posting teh data to http://evergreens.bitrix24.ru
i think posting to this url might need some kind of authentication like HTTP headers or something like that. This may be needed for the website to know which user is posting the data